# Scipy Spline producing an array full of zeros

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, spline

I am attempting to smooth a curve using spline in the Scipy module. I am using Python 2.7 on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine. I am pretty sure I have the code written correctly but I get a numpy array full of zeros for my y axis. Here's the code:

```
 #Smooth Chart Curves
def interp(self, x, y):          
    xx = np.array(x)
    yy = np.array(y)     
    xnew = np.linspace(xx.min(), xx.max(), 300)
    ynew = spline(xx, yy, xnew)
    xnew = np.array(xnew).tolist()
    ynew = np.array(ynew).tolist()  
    return xnew, ynew
```

I begin by passing a list of six numbers to both x and y variables. The `xnew` variable works fine, but `ynew = spline(xx, yy, xnew)` creates a numpy array that is filled with 300 zeros.

I am passing the following as x and y:

```
x = [2800.0, 2002.0, 1234.0, 800.0, 450.0, 0]
y = [5.0, 9.1, 15.3, 20.9, 25.4, 27.2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your x axis needs to be monotonically increasing for interpolation to work. Maybe it is a typo, but `y` looks much more like the x axis to me.

If it really isn't:

```
xx = np.array(x)
sx = np.argsort(xx)
xx = xx[sx]
yy = np.array(y)
yy = yy[sx]
```

will sort both `x` and `y` so that `x` is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: The axes are correct. I'll just reverse everything and it should work. Thank you.